# Are there standard advertising banner sizes?

Tags: advertising, banners

I'm designing a new site and for the first time I want to incorporate 3rd party advertising. I haven't chosen an advertising partner yet.

Are there standard banner sizes I should be designing for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most advertising agencies stick to a pseudo-standard for banner sizes.

[You can find them here](http://www.iab.net/iab_products_and_industry_services/508676/508767/Ad_Unit). In case that link ever goes dead, the most common in use are (in px):

- 486x60 (Full Banner)
- 397x72 (Navigation)
- 120x240 (Vertical Banner)
- 120x90 (Button)
- 120x60 (Button)
- 88x31 (Micro Button)
- 234x60 (Half Banner)
- 160x600 (Vertical Tower)
- 125x125 (Square)